# Return data form Express js EJS template view to node.js server side

Tags: jquery, node.js, sqlite

I am struggling with sending data from the frontend to a backend API.

How can I send data using a POST request from an Express EJS template view to a Node.js Web server API using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve my problem, and hope someone will find this answer useful.

I just needed to grab some variables on client side (jQuery) and pass them to server side. I found out that req.body object can do the trick. This is a simple example

#### Client side

```
var name = 'John';
var surname = 'Doe';

var users={
"name": name,
"surname": surname
};
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'xml/html/script/json',
//JSON.stringify must be included or 400 bad request will occur
     data: JSON.stringify(users),  
     contentType: 'application/json',
     url: '/users'
});
```

#### Server side

```
app.post('/users', function (req, res) {
       console.log(req.body);
       console.log(req.body.name);
       console.log(req.body.surname);
});
```

#### Console log

```
{ name: 'John', surname: 'Doe' }
John
Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

you usually do it that through a POST request

// Client side

```
<form id="nameForm" action = "/something" method = "post" name = "something">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nameInput">Enter your Name: </label>
            <input type="fname" class="form-control" id="playerName" placeholder="Name" name = "playerName">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit_button" disabled>Enter</button>
        </form>

// Server side
app.post('/something', function (req, res) {

        // Do something
    });
```